# detecting 400 response without JSON response

Tags: json, angular

i have save method i want to handle
 POST http://localhost:4200/api/createuser 400 (Bad Request)

but I'm not getting an error responses from the back-end

i tried

```
 if(res.status = 400) {
```

but no luck

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
if(res.status === 400) {

}
```

In the snippet of the question you are *assigning* status to 400 and not checking *if* it is equal to 400 or not.

Comment: i tried this before as well and still no luck i fixed it from the back end